# Best way to give a table a title for accessibility?

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility

I want to give a title or heading to a table. For sighted users this will be hidden as the context is obvious, but for screenreaders what is the best way to mark this up? The table is for opening times so that is the title/ caption/ heading/ etc.

Comment: When you write `will be hidden`, I hope you mean negative text-indent (out of the viewport, far far away on the left, what WordPress calls `.visually-hidden`) and not `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`? If you have to support IE6/7 and they don't want to move the caption, you can place text in a `span` in the caption and apply CSS to the span...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `<caption>` for a title. Even though the caption tag is with the table element, it accepts block level tags, so people wrap the text in a heading tag. The `summary` attribute can be used to provide a descriptions.
See webUsability's [guide about these two topics](http://www.usability.com.au/resources/tables.cfm#identifying).

Comment: `summary` *attribute* for descriptions of structure and purpose of the table in HTML4. In HTML5 `aria-describedby` is supposed to be used instead of summary (see http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2011Apr/0091.html) but the rationale for that change makes no sense.